# Batching model output problem in Arcgis 10.2!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, batch

I built a simple model for projecting raster from one coordinate system to another and it works fine but when i try to batch it, so i can convert more then one raster it generates only the first raster, in tiff, and on the same directory rather than the one i specify in the model using values and path.
[image]

And when i use iterate raster it continues forever and generate only the raster one, the second and then that's it, it continue endlessly and it keeps deleting the first raster.

This is the other model
[image]

and the iterate parameters
[image]

Project raster parameters and output parameter
[image]

[image]

Comment: Rather than running your model in batch model, consider using a raster iterator, conceptually easier to understand an use. So look at the Help file for model iterators.

Comment: But want to manually select only some rasters from a certain folder

Comment: And when i use iterate raster it continues forever and generate only the raster one, the second and then that's it, it continue endlessly and it keeps deleting the first raster.

Comment: You need to amend your question and show us this new model with iterator Along with the iterator parameters.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, can you also show the parameters of the Project Raster tool too? Looking at your model I cannot see why it would "continue endlessly". It should only loop the number of jpeg files in the folder. Also I assume the Parse Path tooth creating %PATH% is being used to construct the full path name to the projected raster? This is why I am asking you to show the project parameters as it is not clear what you are doing with the output of the other Parse path tool?

Comment: I added the extra info

Comment: Ok the input raster for your project tool should be the output of the iterator, which is called raster. Go into Project tool click on the drop down for that parameter and you should see the model input called raster with a blue recycling symbol, use that. Other than that everything else looks fine.

Comment: I already did it twice, it completed without errors but generates only two rasters and it takes the time like it does all the rasters.

Comment: Really not sure why it would do 2 then fail on the rest as the model looks OK to me. Is there something odd about raster 3 which upsets the model? Try projecting that individually to see if any weird error occurs?

Comment: What about skipping those files that already were projected?

Comment: If i don't script the output path and name it works ok but it saves the images by default in tiff format, i want them in jpg, where can i change this default parameters in arcgis so that exporting raster could be in jpg by default

Comment: Just change the file extension in the output name from X.tif to X.jpg

Comment: Yes but it can be done in the case with one image, i want to let it blank so it export the all rasters by default on the same directory like it does normally. But when i leave it blank it exports in tiff format by default.

Comment: Try setting Name and PATH as prerequisites for Project Raster.